# l2 compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Definined the mapping T: [image] -> [image] so that: [image] where [image]
I'd like to show that if T is a compact operator then [image]
I thought i could negate my thesis and then show that T would not be compact but i wasn't able to show it. Has anyone an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\alpha$ is not in $c_0$, then you can find a number $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(\alpha(n_k))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $|\alpha(n_k)| \ge \varepsilon$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Use this to prove that the sequence $(Te_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\ell^2$ has no convergent subsequence (where $e_n \in \ell^2$ denotes the $n$-the canonical unit vector).

Comment: +1. Q: Is $\alpha\in c_0$ sufficient to imply that $T$ is compact?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Yes, $T$ is compact if and only if $\alpha \in c_0$. One way to see this is as follows: If $\alpha \in c_0$, then it can be approximated (with respect to the sup norm) by sequences with only finitely many non-zero entries. The corresponding multiplication operators thus have finite rank and approximate $T$ with respect to the operator norm; hence, $T$ is compact.